# Consume an esv bible web service

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-rest

I am going to consume a public web service at [ESV Bible.](http://www.esvapi.org/api/#sample) in my personal web site.

I already got the API key. For the general test, "IP" can be the key. There is an asp code for it.

```
<%
 'Reference Search
  key = "IP"
  strSearch = "John 1"
  passage = Server.URLEncode(strSearch)
  options = "include-passage-references=true"
  set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  objHTTP.open "GET", "www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key=" & _
  key & "&passage=" & passage & "&" & options, false
  objHTTP.send
  Response.Write(objHTTP.responseText)
 %>
```

But I use asp.net mvc 4, I am going to press a button in a view then pop up a new window or create a html web page to display the response.

How to modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the WebClient for this, from the System.Net namespace

```
var client = new WebClient();
var query = string.Format("www.esvapi.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key={0}&passage={1}&options={2}", "IP", Server.UrlEncode(strSearch),options);
var result = client.DownloadString(query);
```

I haven't put this through the IDE, so you might need to check it a bit

Comment: I have to place these code in Razor, add @? And you return the response as a string?

Comment: in a controller, you can then choose how you want to display, such as returning a contentresult from the action and consuming it using ajax, or passing it out as the model of a view and displaying it in there.